# Converting the request to an array in Facebook PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
$user = $request->getGraphObject->asArray();
```

What's wrong with this line, was trying to convert the returned data of the use to an array.

```
    $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
    $request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $request = $request->execute();
    $user = $request->getGraphObject->asArray();
    print_r($user);
```

I am getting this error..
[14-Jan-2016 10:11:06 America/New_York] PHP Notice: Undefined property: Facebook\FacebookResponse::$getGraphObject in /home/skoolynk/public_html/app/init.php on line 15
[14-Jan-2016 10:11:06 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function asArray () on a non-object in /home/skoolynk/public_html/app/init.php on line 15

Comment: Does  `$request->getGraphObject()` work (i.e. a method call)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $request->getGraphObject->asArray();
```

should be

```
$user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/5.0.0

Comment: thanks Alex but i tried it and it failed, i changed my approach to this:

Comment: $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);
  $response = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
  $response = $response->execute();
    $object = $response->getGraphObject();
  print_r($object);

Comment: it works well though you have to include, use Facebook\FacebookRequest;